# Calculate address from latitude and longitude in google API (More than one address calculation in one request)

Tags: php, geocoding, google-geocoder

This function for Reveres Geocoding works well for me. I have to display the address in the information window of a marker, and there are more then 200 in one map. I built the code below and it works perfectly. However, Google's API request limit of 2500/day gets exceeded easily. 
Is there any way in I can `bulk request` Google's API?

Our project is currently a small one, so buying more requests/day isn't an option for us.

```
<?php 
function getaddress($lat,$lng)
{
  $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
  $json = @file_get_contents($url);
  $data=json_decode($json);
  $status = $data->status;
  if($status=="OK")
  return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
  else
  return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think so.. maybe you can cache the addresses..

Comment: bulk request for address calculation is possible brother?
as per my logic i thought it through array but if there is any other way please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't "bulk query" a bunch of addresses and have it only count as one request when using the [standard API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits#standard-usage-limits).  Each lookup counts as a request.

[There are other APIs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/geocoding-api-comparison) that don't have limits, or allow more lookups, like MapQuest.  If you're hitting the daily limit with Google, try using another API.

Comment: Is mapquest geocoding api gives accurate results as compare to google geocoding api ???

Comment: @BhavinV see here for a comparison: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/geocoding-api-comparison

Comment: ohk great.. i thoroughly read the excelsheet of comparisons of API. 
And your suggestion of using mapquest API is better than other APIs. 

Thank you for the reply :)